# Writing a rails route that doesn't accept get query params

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I want to match a specific route but not that route with any get query params.

Lets say I have a route like this:

`get '/home', to: 'home#home`

This works great for `/home` but how to I 404 `/home?foo=bar`?

Comment: Is there any way this question could be rephrased?

Answer (score 1):

If `?foo=bar` makes no sense in your app it will have no effect at all.

Visiting `/home?foo=bar` will end seeing `/home`. This is quite a convention. Why do you need 404?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an advanced constraint.
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints

```
class NoQueryParamsConstraint
  def matches?(request)
    request.query_parameters.blank?
  end
end


get "/home", to: 'home#home', constraints: NoQueryParamsConstraint.new
```